# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied - But parameter WAS supplied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have what seems like a common problem but without any obvious errors.

I've already seen all related threads and I can see no similarity to my problem because I am not making any "obvious" mistake, at least not similar to the others.

My stored proc declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddEventTemp]
    @iUserID int,
    @iVerb int,
    @iObject int,
    @iResult int,
    @nTransactionID numeric Output
```

And the code:

```
var userId = 9530;
var verb = 2;
var objectId = 15;
var transactionId = 0;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand('sp_AddEventTemp', connection)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iUserID", userId)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iVerb", verb)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iObject", objectId)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iResult", 0)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nTransactionID", 0)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    });

    // execute  
    connection.Open();

    transactionId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    connection.Close();
}

return transactionId;
```

And I get:

```
Procedure or function 'sp_AddEventTemp' expects parameter '@iResult' which was not supplied
```

Even though it clearly IS supplied!

I did this test by running this on SQL server directly:

```
sp_AddEventTemp 9530, 2, 15, 0, 0
```

And it worked perfectly. I got: `(1 row(s) affected)`

So there is nothing wrong with the stored procedure itself. There must be something in the code and I can't figure it out because it looks correct to me.

I do the same for other similar stored procedures and they all work fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could it be some sort of follow-up-error due to the mismatch between the procedure's datatype for @nTransactionID and your usage of it in the code (numeric/int)?

Comment: Don't think so because there is no such thing as SqlDbType.Numberic
It's still a mystery to me, but I got it working by using a workaround